# Cannot login into Verdaccio

Tags: npm, proxy, verdaccio

I have just installed Verdaccio on my computer. I have changed nothing in the config file, apart from adding proxy_related info:

```
http_proxy: http://proxy.ip:8080
https_proxy: https://proxy.ip:8080
no_proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1
```

After starting the process, I have tried to login to the registry from the library project workspace

```
npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873
```

But I get this error:

```
npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable - POST http://localhost:4873/-/v1/login
```

If I try to reach http://localhost:4873/ from my browser, I can see the Verdaccio webpage.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what kind of environment you are trying this (work, home, etc.) but, for me, my problem was that behind a corporate firewall I have to configure the NPM proxy (http and https), so adding the localhost as an exception to noproxy config attribute of NPM, it worked for me.

```
npm config set noproxy localhost
```

Try to change yours, from **no_proxy** to **noproxy**, maybe it is simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

update your npm to the last version

```
npm install -g npm
```